# how to mark and un mark rows in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have one table view contain static group created via storyboard I want to use check mark to change setting or choosing different rows but I don't know how should I do that, to check and uncheck the rows, programmatically or via xcode

would you please help me !

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This design is certainly OK for in-house deployment, but if you plan to upload to app store, consider replacing accessory views with individual `UISwitch` objects, for example, the way it is done in the settings app.

Comment: Also you can use [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) if you want to make a settings screen for your app.

Comment: I halfway agree with dasblinkenlight.  I think the bottom part should probably use `UISwitch` to turn off and on the different notification settings, but I think the check mark accessory is probably the best way to handle the top part where you just want to select one language or the other.

Answer (score 2):

You change the UITableViewCell [accessory type](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

As for what is selected, you use the above property in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: but I'm using static group via interface builder can I use this property in my code?

Comment: You have build the interface, but the method that executes the action (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) needs to be coded.

Answer (score 0):

For the French/English section, you'll need to have one checked by default I assume.
In your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"English"]) 
{
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Then, whenever the cell is tapped, you'll need to figure out with one has been tapped, and then uncheck the other.

in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
if(indexPath.section ==0 && indexPath.row ==0) {
    UITableViewCell * otherCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
    otherCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   }
 else if(indexPath.section ==0 && indexPath.row ==1) {
    UITableViewCell * otherCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    otherCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   }
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot that cell wasn't passed through in the method.
before the code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, add in:
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Answer (score 0):

You can mark or unmark row using

```
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

You add above method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, manage all checks in array and reload the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can check or uncheck the view, that is great, but where are you saving the model?  What property are you using to save the information about what language is being selected?

I would suggest that you have some sort of enumerated data type that holds the language you are selecting and include it in you `.h` file:

```
enum language {english, french};

@interface TesterProjectViewController : UIViewController
{
    enum language selectedLanguage;
}
```

Next I would select a language on your `viewDidLoad:` as your default language, or use `NSUserDefaults` to select the language they selected last.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self->selectedLanguage = english;

}
```

Then, I would use my `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` functions to keep up with which language needs to be selected, and which `UITableViewCell` needs to have the accessory view:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                self->selectedLanguage = english;
                break;

            case 1:
                self->selectedLanguage = french;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    [theTableView reloadData];
}
```

The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method is used to set which language you are using in your MODEL.  Then the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is used to set your VIEW to match your MODEL.  You may wish to go ahead and set the check mark in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but I prefer to keep it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so that it is always correct if my data gets reloaded, like so:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *theCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];


    //  You may set up the cell differently or do whatever setup you need here:


    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        if(self->selectedLanguage == english && indexPath.row==0)
            theCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        else if(self->selectedLanguage == french && indexPath.row==1)
            theCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        else 
            theCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    //More cell setup can go here, or setup cells for different rows/sections.

    return theCell;
}
```

Also, as others have noted, I would use `UISwitch` for the notification selections at the bottom as they are not "radio" type selections, but rather each selection is an on/off type selection.

I hope this has helped you!

Comment: thanks but I'm using static table when I use your last method my label doesn't appear , is there any way to do that via interface builder?

Comment: Didn't realize they were static.  It may not be working, though, because you didn't change the reuseIdentifier.  I just chose "cell" but you need to put in whatever you set as the Identifier for the cells.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}else{
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
}

- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {

//add your own code to set the cell accesory type.
return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```